# Javascript - Undefined array value after string .split

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

I wanted to check if a string is palindrome, but I have a problem in reversing a string. I know there's a lot of Questions about palindrome in Javascript, but i want to find it on my way and I still can't find the solution on those Questions.

**Code**

```
function reverse(string){
  var str = string;
  var split = str.split("");
  var newStr= "";

  for(var i=split.length; i>=0; i--){
     newStr += split[i];
  }

  console.log(newStr); 
}

var str= 'blue';

reverse(str);
```

**Results**

```
"undefinedeulb"
```

**Question**

As we can see, the results was an undefined value at the start of the string.
I tested this code with PHP script, and It works fine. How could this be a problem with Javascript? and How to get rid of it?

Comment: `str.split("").reverse().join("")` reverses a string

Comment: You are trying to access `split[split.length]` which is undefined. You are off by one

Comment: FYI, the reason why it seems to work in PHP is that the undefined index seems to be coerced to an empty string somehow. It's still wrong though.

Comment: Exactly Felix! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of an array starts with **0**, for example in

`var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];`

the last one is `arr[4]` // "e"

but `arr.length` is 5,
so `arr[5`] is `undefined`.

So `arr[arr.length]` is **always** `undefined`!

In your example the first iteration, `i` equals `split.length` is `undefined`, therefore try

`for(var i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Comment: Alternatively: `for(var i=split.length; i--;) {}`

Comment: That's true, and I also agree with adeneo's comment that there is a much simpler way to implement this functionality, but since Billy wanted to figure it out themselves I figured I'd leave it as close to their implementation as possible

Answer (score 0):

split.length is equal to 4, but because arrays are zero-indexed you need to start at 3 and move down to zero.

```js
function reverse(string){
  var str = string;
  var split = str.split("");
  var newStr= "";

  for(var i = split.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
     newStr += split[i]; console.log(i);
  }

  console.log(newStr); 
}

var str= 'blue';

reverse(str);
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks Jeremy S